# Seagate Barracuda (Compute series) Compress Disk Issue

Tags: hard-disk

I just bought a new drive last few days, which is Seagate ST2000DM008-2FR102, which is a 2TB capacity of 64 Mb Cache. This is my first time I bought from Seagate since WD is out of stock and why not try another mainstream brand. It's known widely that Seagate also one of the successful hard drive manufacturer in this age, until I encounter the following uncertainty;

As usual with my WD drives, be it 2.5' or 3.5', I always check the 
**Compress this drive to save disk space**
option at the bottom, to give me more spaces. What surprised me for the first time was, all my folders and files inside this disk are, **apparently missing**  in the Explorer after a shutdown and reboot. But the **volume is consumed**, which means they are there in the disk, but **I can't see it**. Luckily enough before I return the disk to the retail where I bought it, I already have old copies from old drive.

The technician at the place that I bought the drive told me **never to tick the option again** next time as it will results in the same case (He did format the disk afterward), which I find it unrelated, unreliable answer to convince your customer about the disk. Well, after a few test (copying files and reboot) it seems that it's true, never to compress the disk, but only the folders/files only.

Has anyone has any explanation about this issue on Seagate HDD or experienced the same case before?

Comment: Compressing the whole drive, especially a 2 TB one, is indeed unusual, and you may want to check if you are really benefiting from enabling compression. If the disk is filled with photos or videos, enabling compression provides no benefits, since those are already compressed (but does create a drawback of slower read-writes). If your disk is filled with terabytes of text-based data (such as the logs), you may check for a more optimal way to store the data.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko so you're saying that there is no need to compress hdd of 2tb and above? Or just 2tb? Yes my disks are usually filled with medias. I compressed the disk cause i can see that the size on disk and actually size are indeed differs.

Comment: If by media, you mean photos and videos, then, as I stated, those files cannot be compressed. An .mpg video or a JPEG image are already compressed themselves. When I mentioned 2TB, is simply in relation with the contents. It was not unusual fifteen years before to see people enabling compression on a PC which has a 20 GB drive: saving even 500 MB would be a win (2.5% of the total space). Now, on a disk or several terabytes filed mostly with photos/videos, compression would be more a burden than anything else.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko yes i know about image and video compression. Such JPEG format also means the image already compressed. The thing is about, compressing the whole big files. Ad I mentioned, it never happened on 2 of my WD drives before. One of them already being used for 4 years and still 100% in Health.